# Diference between $var = array($key => array()) VS $var[] = array($key => array())

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a question about these 2 ways of declaring the array (I thought they would be the same):

```
$result[$zone->id]['activities'][$activity->id] = array(
  'title' => $activity->title,
  'image' => $activity->image
);

$result[$zone->id]['activities'] = array(
  $activity->id => array(
    'title' => $activity->title,
    'image' => $activity->image
  )
);
```

So my goal is to provide an array that is sorted by the Zone then by it's activities listed under the array of "activities".

The first array gives me the following result which is correct for my example:

```
array(3) {
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(15) "Oftalmologistas"
    ["image"]=>
    string(28) "logotipo_1575907014_4232.png"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Ã“ticas"
    ["image"]=>
    string(28) "logotipo_1575907021_1130.png"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(21) "Outras especialidades"
    ["image"]=>
    string(28) "logotipo_1575907034_8988.png"
  }
}
```

But the second array gives me the last activity found and replaces the two above it doesn't add them to array instead it replaces them.

```
array(1) {
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(21) "Outras especialidades"
    ["image"]=>
    string(28) "logotipo_1575907034_8988.png"
  }
}
```

My goal here is to understand the diference syntax between them why the first adds them to array while the seconds replaces. Also any other way of declaring the array to the same first value. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you think they would be that same?

Comment: `['activities'] = array($activity->id)` is the same as `['activities'] = [$activity->id]` while you do `['activities'][$activity->id]` on the first example

Comment: Where i use ['activities'][$activity->id] = array() in the first one and in the second i use ['activities'] = array($activity->id => array()) as key in the second would do the same result right as I am setting in both the $activity->id as a KEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for first example

```
$result[$zone->id]['activities'][$activity->id] = array(
  'title' => $activity->title,
  'image' => $activity->image
);
```

You are assigning value to key ***"$activity->id"***

> Here as id gone be dynamic it will create new key everytime.

In second example

```
$result[$zone->id]['activities'] = array(
  $activity->id => array(
    'title' => $activity->title,
    'image' => $activity->image
  )
);
```

You are assiging value/array to ***activities***.

> So every time you try to assign value to activities key it will
>   replace it.

Comment: Yes I think that's it thanks for explaining that way! I think i got it now but have only one question based on that would there be any other way to achieve the first array result?

Comment: you can achive it by creating one array with activity id and assign it to activities key. But it will have overhead of creating one extra array. like $activities = array(1=>values,2=>values) and then $result[$zone->id]['activities'] = $activities

Answer (score 1):

this is just simple nested arrays with different keys and values for better understanding i change it to this code:

```
$result[100]['activities'][200] = array(
  'title' => 4000,
  'image' => 3000
);

$result[300]['product'] = array(
  444444=> array(
    'title' => 5000,
    'image' => 6000
  )
);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
```

first we have two array and inside each of them again there is another two arrays with different key and values if you look at this picture i uploaded i think you can understand completely.

[nested array result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESluu.png)

Comment: Ok but can you test it in a foreach() loop and see the results using the same structure and the last should replace the array with the last value while the first array should simply add them